# How to handle multiple queries in PHP, including multiple TEMPORARY tables

Tags: php, mysql

This question is in relation to the answer of [another question][1] that I've posted a year ago.

Basically, I need to translate the answer in PHP and I don't even know where to start. Should I use 6 queries? Should I concatenate every query into 1 query? Should I use `mysqli_multi_query`?

I just need some advice, tips, and I will do the rest, I will do the research needed on how to achieve this in PHP.

This is the query that works perfectly and that I need to translate in PHP:

```
-- Query 1
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
SELECT
    w.work_id,
    w.name wname,
    r.sort_name rsortname,
    CONCAT(r.seo_url, '.', r.recording_id) as rurl
FROM
    WORK AS w
    JOIN recording AS r ON w.work_id = r.work_id
    JOIN `release` AS rl ON r.release_id = rl.release_id
WHERE
    r.is_performer = 1
    AND r.is_video = 0
ORDER BY
    w.work_id,
    - rl.released_year DESC,
    - rl.released_month DESC,
    - rl.released_day DESC,
    rl.release_id;

-- Query 2
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x
SELECT
    MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    work_id;

-- Query 3
SELECT
    work_id,
    wname,
    rurl
FROM
    x
    JOIN t ON x.ID = t.ID
ORDER BY
    rsortname;

-- Query 4, 5
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE x;
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use 6 queries?

Yes, and if these queries depend on variable from PHP then you should use prepared statements to execute them.

> Should I concatenate every query into 1 query?

Definitely not. They are not one query, they are all separate and you should execute them separately.

> Should I use mysqli_multi_query?

Never! Forget that this function even exists. It is difficult to use and completely unnecessary. Just use prepared statements or command-line interface in MySQL for administrative tasks.

Comment: Noticed that in Query 1 there are 2 statements... a CREATE and SELECT. Should those be 2 queries o one query?

Comment: @Marco How can they be one query? As you said yourself they are two statements, so they will require you to execute them one after another.

Comment: @Marco the first query is create table select, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html And this answer is wrong, the queries can be combined into one big query. Whether you should do that is a different question. Each temporary table can be expressed by a derived table (subquery in the from clause), the autoincrement field in the first temp table by generating ranking.